# VSTS: Difference between default and compare branch

Tags: azure-devops

In my `git` repository I have three branches: master: *default*, dev: *compare*, and temp.

[image]

When I create a `Pull Request` from temp branch it defaults to `dev` as the target.

[image]

It is in contradiction with what [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/manage-your-branches#change-your-default-branch) says:

> Change the default branch used to merge code into when your team
>   creates new pull requests. This is useful when you want to use a
>   branch other than master for the main line of development in your
>   repo.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some quick tests in my VSTS tenant. It looks like the default branch of a new pull request is always the ***Compare*** branch, rather than the ***Default*** branch. So if you set your master branch as ***Compare branch***, it should become to the default for new pull requests.

Not sure if it is bug of VSTS, or if they change the behavior of pull request without updating the doc.

**Update**:

I did some further research. It turned out that this change was introduced in a [Oct 2016 feature roll out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2016/oct-12-team-services#configurable-compare-branch):

> You can now set your compare branch to something other than the
>   default branch. This setting will be remembered on a per-user basis.
>   Pull requests and new branches created from the Branches page will be
>   based off the branch you set as the compare branch.

So the doc needs to be updated.

Comment: Created a feedback here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/200210/the-default-branch-wont-be-default-item-of-target.html

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Thanks. Would you please update your answer as well?

Comment: @Hans This is not my answer, I just submit a feedback and add the comment to Morpheus's answer for additional information.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT Oops, my bad! Just checked `MSFT` suffix :)

Answer (score 14):

For **default branch**, it helps you to treat the branch as default when cloning the git repo locally or creating a PR.

Such as if you treat `master` branch as default branch (by default), when you cloned the git repo locally, the local branch is `master`. And when you creating a PR, it will automatically treat `master` branch as the  target branch.

For **compare branch**, it helps you to decide how many commits on the other branches are behind or ahead by comparing commits on other branches with the compare branch.

[image]

Such as for above example, `develop` branch is compare branch, and `master` branch and `nn1` branch are compare with `develop` branch.

For comparing `master` branch with `develop` branch, there has 0 commits behind and 0 commit ahead (`master` branch same as `develop` branch). For comparing `nn1` branch with `develop` branch, there are 3 commits behind and 48 commits ahead.